# Parity Check Matrix From Hamming code length 15

Tags: coding-theory

I am not able to figure out whats the method the calculate the parity check matrix. I am not sure if this is the method which is 1 ,2 3,.........15. So I can write its binary 0001, 0010, 0011,..... 1111 and make it a 4X15 matrix will that be a parity check matrix

Comment: hello the first post reviewer here, i removed some tags , also can you give more info over your problem also did you see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_code  , which pariti did you mean EXACTLY

Comment: Hello I did go through the link but its hard for me to understand since I am new to this. In my question it says "Parity check Matrix H" its a Introduction to Error coding question.

Comment: that looks more like Hamming (7,4) see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming%287,4%29 than Hamming (15,11) maybe study Hamming (7,4) first and then try a new question, GOOD LUCK Think about how many data bits you want and which hamming distance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is indeed a parity check matrix for a length 15 binary Hamming code.

In general, let $C$ be the code with parity check matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{1}_2 & \mathbf{2}_2 & \cdots & \mathbf{r}_2
\end{pmatrix},$$

where $\mathbf{k}_2$ denotes the column vector containing the digits of $k$ in binary, padded with the appropriate number of $0$s at the top. Then $C$ is a length $2^r-1$ binary Hamming code.

Comment: Thank you. I have to Decode a vector y = 111110000000000 from that, can you suggest me how to go about it

Comment: Are you familiar with syndrome decoding? Let's call the parity check matrix $H$. Calculate the syndrome $\mathbf{s} := H \mathbf{y}^T$. Then find the vector $\mathbf{e}$ of Hamming weight 1 such that $H \mathbf{e}^T = \mathbf{s}$. Decode to $\mathbf{y} + \mathbf{e} \pmod{2}$.

In this case there's a shortcut. Because the columns of the parity check matrix are written in order in binary, we know that if $\mathbf{s} = (\mathbf{k}_2)^T$, then $\mathbf{e}$ is all $0$s with a $1$ in the $k^\text{th}$ position.

Comment: Let's try this out with the vector $\mathbf{y} = 101010101010001$. Calculate $\mathbf{s} = H \mathbf{y}^T = (1101)^T = (\mathbf{13}_2)^T$. Therefore $\mathbf{e} = 000000000000100$, so you can decode to $\mathbf{y} + \mathbf{e} = 101010101010101$.

Comment: I figured it out, my answer is coming 111101111111111 I am not sure if its right?

Comment: And could you explain me how do we find weight of the Matrix?

Comment: The (Hamming) weight of a vector is the number of nonzero entries in the vector. For example, 111110000000000 has weight 5.

Comment: For your vector $\mathbf{y} = 111110000000000$, I calculated the syndrome $\mathbf{s} = H\mathbf{y}^T = (0001)^T = (\mathbf{1}_2)^T$, so $\mathbf{e} = 100000000000000$. So $\mathbf{y}$ decodes to $\mathbf{y} + \mathbf{e} = 011110000000000$.

Comment: By the way, $\mathbf{z} = 111101111111111$ can't be a codeword because $H \mathbf{z}^T = (0101)^T \ne \mathbf{0}$ (the code is defined as the vectors $\mathbf{c}$ where $H \mathbf{c}^T = \mathbf{0}$).

Answer (score 0):

If the parity check matrix of a code has a column that has only zeroes in it,
then the code has minimum distance $1$. If there are no zero columns but there are two identical columns, then the code has minimum distance $2$. A Hamming code has minimum distance $3$. So, what can you conclude about the columns of the parity
check matrix of a Hamming code? How many columns does the parity check matrix have? From this, can you figure out how many *rows* the parity check matrix has?

Comment: Minimum distance 3 means it will have 3 identical columns in that case we can have 15 columns and i am not sure about the row.

Comment: Dilip Sarwate can you please guide me ow to go about it?

Comment: Minimum distance $3$ does _not_ mean that there are three identical columns. You have missed the point being made. Begin by figuring out _why_ when there are two identical columns, the minimum distance (and minimum weight) is _exactly_ $2$ by _constructing_ a codeword of weight $2$.

Comment: Weight 2 means eg vector [1 0 1 0 0] in this the weight is 2 since there are two ones. I am confused about the distance

Comment: I am not sure if this is the method which is 1 ,2 3,.........15. So I can write 0001, 0010, 0011,..... 1111 and make it a 4X15 matrix will that be a parity check matrix.