# Hamming code of length $15$. How many code words are there? Which of the following are code words?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, coding-theory

Hi I'm trying to solve this problem but have some difficulty.

Write down a check matrix for the Hamming code of length $15$. How many code words are there? Assuming that the columns of your matrix are ordered in the natural order, which of the following are codewords?

$c_1 =011010110111000$

$c_2 = 00000000000011$

$c_3 =110110110111111$

I found a very similar question here at the forum: [Parity Check Matrix From Hamming code length 15](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/935946/parity-check-matrix-from-hamming-code-length-15/936007#comment1931088_936007)

From that I was pretty much handed the Check matrix (assuming it was right).

$H = \begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\0&0&0&1&1&1&1&0&0&0&0&1&1&1&1&\\0&1&1&0&0&1&1&0&0&1&1&0&0&1&1\\1&0&1&0&1&0&1&0&1&0&1&0&1&0&1\end{bmatrix}$

My first question would be: why does this constitute a Check matrix?

Second I need to find the number of code words there are. I know that the solution is given by $2^k$ where $k$ is the dimension, but how do I get that from the check matrix?

Thirdly, in order to see if $c_i$ is a word I have the following to rely on:
$s:=Hy^T$, $He^T=s$, decode by $y+e$ $(mod$ $2)$.

For the first word I get: $Hy^T=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&1&0\end{bmatrix}$, the sixth column in the check matrix. Thus $e=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$. Now $e+y$ $(mod$ $2)$ is $\begin{bmatrix}0&1&1&0&1&0&1&1&0&1&1&0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$. Frome here I don't know how to proceed in order to show that $c_1$ is a code word. Help, please.

Comment: To show that some $c$ is a codeword, you just have to show that $Hc^T = 0$ (zero vector with four components). And if you find that $Hc^T \ne 0$, you can conclude that $c$ is not a codeword.

Comment: For a parity-check matrix of a binary Hamming code of length $15$, you should know that it is obtained by writing as columns the binary representations of the numbers from $1$ to $15$ (and any order of these columns gives a valid parity-check matrix, it will just affect the position of the information bits and check bits).

Comment: For the $k$ thing, you can recall that for a binary Hamming code of length $n=2^m -1$, the value of $k$ is $\color{blue}{k=n-m}$.